# var_dump returns NULL Json object after json_decode

Tags: php, rest, curl, libcurl

Hello I make a curl POST action in terminal(i tried also in POSTMAN) for post some data in a php file

The curl call is :

```
curl -iX POST http://localhost/rest_api/index.php 
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   
  -d '{
      "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Building:store005",
      "type": "Building"
     }'
```

The response is :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 09 Aug 2020 14:14:37 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.43 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.2.32 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.32.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.32
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 105
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8;

array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(29) "urn:ngsi-ld:Building:store005"
  ["type"]=>
  string(8) "Building"
}
```

Also my index.php file is:

```
<?php 
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
   header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8;');

   $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
   $object = json_decode($json, true);
   die(var_dump($object));

?>
```

The problem is that in the website the var_dump is NULL,while it should print the json object.
Where is my false?

Comment: You want to print the `json` object or `php` array?

Comment: @AndrewHardiman `json` object

Comment: Then try `echo $json`

Comment: @RiggsFolly It doesn't appear nothing

Comment: Why are you doing `json_decode`?

Comment: I thought that i need that but ok I understood that it converts the Json to array. But this isn't the problem I think right?

Comment: What is the contents of the variable `$json`?

Comment: You could loose the 2 headers, I dont think they are adding anything. But if `echo $json;` shows nothing then you are not sending anything to this script

Comment: @AndrewHardiman `{
"id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Building:store005",
"type": "Building"
}` It appears in curl like in example above but in the website it isn't appear

Comment: @RiggsFolly Is there something wrong with my curl action?

Comment: what does `var_dump($json)` return?

Comment: @AndrewHardiman `string(0) ""` this mean that the value don't pass right ?

Comment: "*in the website the var_dump is NULL*" ... could you clarify? Are you saying you are trying to hit `index.php` with a web browser and its returning null? If so, then its because your web browser is not doing a POST with json as the sole body. Unless you are attempting ajax, which you have not mentioned here so I don't think thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the response body:

```
array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(29) "urn:ngsi-ld:Building:store005"
  ["type"]=>
  string(8) "Building"
}
```

That isn't JSON. It looks like a `var_dump()`. Check the endpoint you call!

Comment: Thats not the issue it seems, its confusing in the question; But it goes like this: He is testing `index.php` via command line by passing a body of json. It results OK based on the php code of `var_dump of decoded json`. However when he tries via 'web browser' ... it results in nothing. This is because a web browser is not sending json for php://input to pick up.